# Ceiling fan light fixture comes on with fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I installed a new light fixture on my ceiling fan and apparently did something wrong with the wiring. The lights will only come on when the fan itself is running and are dim. It appears that they are somehow sharing the same power supply, I connected the light fixture to the white and black cords in the fan. I first attempted to connect the light fixture to the blue and white wires but this resulted in neither the fan or lights turning on. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack exchange.  Can you post pictures of the current wiring, and any instructions that came with your fan?

Comment: How many light switches do you have in the wall? Can you post photos of the wiring at both the fan and switch ends?

Comment: I suspect you have a switch loop and disconnected too much stuff. We're gonna need some photos.  You can log in with the credentials you used before (check your email), [edit] your post, then hit the mountains-and-sun icon to add a pic.

Answer (score 1):

White to white.

Black and blue (from the fan/light) both go to the incoming power if you only have a single switch. (three wires in one wire nut)

It sounds like what you did was hook them up in series. They need to be in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate switch wired to operate them separately. Running one off the other is why they turn on and off together.